# How to extract sentence from web pages

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I would like to extract sentences (not just an html-stripped text) from web pages. I wonder if such functionality is supported by popular HTML parsing libraries such as Jsoup?

Thanks,

**Edit**:

Sorry if the post was not clear. I need natural language sentences so not necessarily separated by a dot.

Thanks everyone. I just found this library http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentences/read-me.html and it seems exactly what I want.

Comment: Be more precise. Give an example of an HTML content and tell us what you want to extract.

Comment: Do you talk about "Natural language processing" or is a sentence any list of words seperate by a dot ?

Comment: take a look at [diffbot.com](http://www.diffbot.com), they do it in cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSoup` does provides a very convenient `API` for **extracting** and **manipulating** `data`, in short... Yes it does provide this functionality...

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery for that

`var t = $('p').text();

    var sentences = t.split('.');`

Comment: Might be to simple.. it depends on your exact needs.